# How to know if safe file move on WatchService event is possible?

Tags: java, sftp, nio

While implementing a "sFTP --mv--> sFTP" program I use `WatchService` from the `java.nio` lib to register `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE`. The use case is, that some device drops a file onto a Server in a DMZ, which I'd like to move to another FTP Server in my Domain.

The file transmission onto the first server can take some moments. How can I safely move the file to the 2nd server, because I don't know when the creation process is complete and the file is able to be moved? Is Entry_create the wrong Event to be listened to?

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956262/java-watchservice-gets-informed-before-content-is-copied. Also look at the questions linked to that question, and the questions linked to _those_ questions, and so on.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much 